# Windows 7: prevent auto-restoring of Start Menu icons?

Tags: windows-7, start-menu

Many programs I install put their icons directly into the Start Menu root. Instead of poking around between some dozens of unrelated icons, I have created groups ("Programming", "3D", "Audio" etc.) and dragged icons into these groups. Some installers ask me where to put the icon, I direct them to respective folders and it's OK. Sadly, most installers don't ask anything and put the icon into the root; then I drag these icons by hand.

The problem is that sometimes some icons appear in the root again. These are, in particular, Acrobat Reader, Dropbox, Java, Microsoft Silverlight, among others. I can't trace when it happens, probably with Windows Update. So, once in a while I see in the Start Menu an icon I have once dragged away into a subfolder. I drag the new icon into the same place and it turns out that the icon in the subfolder still exists, so I get an overwrite dialog etc. So, the icons are not moved back but created anew.

Who is doing it? How do I stop this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is happening not because Windows is updating, but because the softwares you mentioned, themselves, are auto-updating. It's as if the update process is remembering your original setup option of creating a shortcut at StartMenu.

First, try disabling those softwares' auto-update and see if those shortcuts stop being created.

Also, for the future, if a setup doesn't allow you to change the shortcut folder, instead of allowing the setup to create the shortcut and moving it manually, you shouldn't allow the setup to create it and then you create a shortcut yourself, manually. I believe this will prevent new shortcuts to be placed at StartMenu root when a software is updated.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Indeed, every time an icon re-appears, it turns out that the program has been updated. I was a bit surprised that some programs (Acrobat Reader and Dropbox) are updating themselves silently without asking anything.